# Excel: Check decimal number in 2 cell and copy Same data in another cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 Cell with string. in A1 i have a 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9 and in B1 i have a 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19. i need a formula to copy all decimal number which is available in both cell. that means in cell A1 and in Cell B1 there are same number is 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9. So, in C1 answer should be 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9.

Note: Data is coming randomly using another formula..

is any one have a formula for this. Please reply. Only formula without VBA code.

[image]

I don't understand how I can found it. Please help..

Comment: Why no VBA? There's no simple way in Excel to split strings by delimiter. You might be able to make a very complicated formula, but that's not really readable, not maintainable. I would consider such a formula "bad design". But anyhow, like [every homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) what have you tried already?

Comment: p.s. googling helps. [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1667757/matching-comma-seperated-values-in-2-different-cells-and-display-non-duplicate-v), but this is exactly what I mean with terrible code. Those formulas are butt-ugly.

Comment: Data is coming randomly using another formula and i want only Excel Formula

Comment: _"i want only Excel Formula"_ yes, but should you? IMHO no. It's not good design.

Comment: I already use below formula. = TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(IF(FIND(TEXTSPLIT($A$1,",",,TRUE,1,),$B$1)>0,TEXTSPLIT($A$1,",",,TRUE,1,),0),"")). but answer came 1.7, 1.8, 1.9

Comment: Ha, great. you're almost there. Just remember the text is not separated by `","`, but by `", "` <- with a space. So you need to trim, or just add the space in the split and join

Comment: it's working now. But if i add one more number in number 2 column with matching number, which is located in Number 1 for example, 1.30. Then result are coming 1.3, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9..

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. I think something went wrong. Just adding the space should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, but just have to remeber the elements are separated by ", ", a comma and a space, not just by a comma.

That would make the code

```
= TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;
    IFERROR(
        IF(FIND(TEXTSPLIT(A1;", ";;TRUE;1);B1)>0;
            TEXTSPLIT(A1;", ";;TRUE;1);
            0);
        ""))
```

(there's probably a neater solution)